# SQL Get the total count of registered user in day by day

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

Can you help me to construct a query. The scenario is this, I want to get the total value of the registered users each day.

Comment: provide your expected output and sample data

Comment: Where is your sample data?

Comment: Hello there! I've updated my post. I include that sample and output data

Comment: Sorry the output is wrong i want it day by day for a week maybe. Example This monday until Sunday

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: I'm using MySQL

Answer (score 0):

```
Select  count(*) 
from    tableName
Where   registered = true 
Group by Date
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your registration timestamp is stored at created_at date-time field and table named say user:

```
SELECT created_at,COUNT(*) as `total registration` FROM `user` GROUP BY (DATE(`user`.`created_at`))
```

Answer (score 0):

The former answers do neither cover the `where` part nor output the dayname.

This should do both and produce what you want:

```
create table #data (
    reg_id int,
    reg_email nvarchar(255),
    reg_date datetimeoffset(7)
)

insert into #data(reg_id, reg_email, reg_date) 
VALUES
(1, 'a', '2018-10-01'),
(2, 'b', '2018-10-01'),
(3, 'c', '2018-10-02'),
(4, 'd', '2018-10-03'),
(5, 'e', '2018-10-01'),
(6, 'f', '2018-10-02'),
(7, 'g', '2018-10-04'),
(8, 'h', '2018-10-05'),
(9, 'i', '2018-10-05'),
(10, 'j', '2018-10-06')

SELECT count(*), datename(dw, reg_date) from #data
where datepart(week, reg_date) = 40
group by reg_date

drop table #data
```

assuming that you are using `sql server` greater or equal 2008!

Answer (score 0):

I finally get the correct data for today and last 7 days. Please refer below query.

```
SELECT 
a.JourneyName,
a.BonusName,
a.Status,
a."Timestamp",
a.MID,
COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DD, a."Timestamp", GETDATE()) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as "Day_1",
COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DD, a."Timestamp", GETDATE()) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as "Day_2",
COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DD, a."Timestamp", GETDATE()) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as "Day_3",
COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DD, a."Timestamp", GETDATE()) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as "Day_4",
COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DD, a."Timestamp", GETDATE()) = 4 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as "Day_5",
COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DD, a."Timestamp", GETDATE()) = 5 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as "Day_6",
COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DD, a."Timestamp", GETDATE()) = 6 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as "Day_7"
FROM
    TableName a
WHERE
a."Timestamp" >= DATEADD(DD, -7, GETDATE())
AND a."Timestamp" <= GETDATE()
GROUP BY``
      a.JourneyName, a.BonusName, a.Status, a."Timestamp", a.MID
```

Total Count per day where Day_1 is today, Day_2 is yesterday and so on.